# Yootheme ZOO - Application layout change in php

Tags: php, joomla

in ZOO Application/templates/uikit/_categories.php have this code:

```
<?php  

    // init vars  
    $i = 0;  
    $columns = $this->params->get('template.categories_cols', 2);  
    reset($this->selected_categories);  

    // render rows  
    while ((list($key, $category) = each($this->selected_categories))) {  
        if ($category && !($category->totalItemCount() || $this->params->get('config.show_empty_categories', false))) continue;  
        if ($i % $columns == 0) echo ($i > 0 ? '</div><hr class="uk-grid-divider"><div class="uk-grid">' : '<div class="uk-grid">');  
        echo '<div class="uk-width-1-'.$columns.'">'.$this->partial('category', compact('category')).'</div>';  
        $i++;  
    }  
    if (!empty($this->selected_categories)) {  
        echo '</div>';  
    }  

?>
```

Render look like this:

```
<div class="uk-grid">  
   <div class="uk-width-1-3"></div>  
   <div class="uk-width-1-3"></div>  
   <div class="uk-width-1-3"></div>  
</div>  

<hr class="uk-grid-divider">  

<div class="uk-grid">  
   <div class="uk-width-1-3"></div>  
   <div class="uk-width-1-3"></div>  
   <div class="uk-width-1-3"></div>  
</div>
```

And I want this (only one div.uk-grid for all div.uk-width* and without hr.uk-grid.divider):

```
<div class="uk-grid">  
   <div class="uk-width-1-3"></div>  
   <div class="uk-width-1-3"></div>  
   <div class="uk-width-1-3"></div>  
   <div class="uk-width-1-3"></div>  
   <div class="uk-width-1-3"></div>  
   <div class="uk-width-1-3"></div>  
</div>
```

Can someone help me with this, i am not good in php?

Thanks.

My modified code which not work :(

```
<?php

    $columns = $this->params->get('template.categories_cols', 2); // I dont know why is at end ", 2"
    reset($this->selected_categories); // I dont know why is needed reset array

    // render rows
    while ((list($key, $category) = each($this->selected_categories))) {

        if ($category && !($category->totalItemCount() || $this->params->get('config.show_empty_categories', false))) { 
    echo '<div class="uk-grid">'; // I dont know why is not rendered
    }
        echo '<div class="uk-width-1-'.$columns.'">'.$this->partial('category', compact('category')).'</div>';
    }
    if (!empty($this->selected_categories)) {
        echo '</div>';
    }

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must have set a parameter to add two columns, that's what kicks in the code that adds the separator.

The name of the parameter is `template.categories_cols` it will be translated though to something in english.

This is a commercially supported extension, you might be able to get some support on their forums

Comment: I tried their forum (http://www.yootheme.com/support/question/58989), but their support is borring, only answer on topics how to change color or change font size. template.categories_cols in this case = 3;

Comment: I cant change categories_cols to 1, because in template settings I have set how many columns I want have, and I want have 3 columns and this number *3 is added to <div class="uk-width-medium-1-*>. I add some modified code to topic, but i dont understand all code, can you look at it and see my notes.

Comment: You should use this instead of the while...each loop:
foreach($this->selected_categories as $key=>$category) {

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to set your columns at 1, then use UIKit's CSS to size your divs. This means you'd want your container class to be `uk-grid uk-grid-width-1-3`, then to remove the `uk-width-1-3` from the inner divs. The added benefit here is that you can vary layout depending on your screen size > [Grid Component - UIKit](https://getuikit.com/docs/grid.html#even-grid-columns).

In your PHP you could remove the columns param all together. Remove the line starting with `$columns...`, the single spot it's echo'd `'.$columns.'`, and you should be all set.

The PHP **was** using your "columns" variable to split divs *(2 was the default)*, but if you tailor the container you can avoid the column assignment altogether.